# What is the correct way of inserting values in to tables and link tables in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to build a database but have become stuck after creating the tables. I have tried inserting values into a table but it gives me the following error:

Error starting at line : 73 in command -

```
INSERT INTO Project(ProjID, ProjName, ProjStartDate) VALUES (00, Project1, DATE '1900-02-14')
```

Error at Command Line : 73 Column : 66
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:
*Action:

I am really struggling to find what is wrong with this but i am new to oracle so am not sure, any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code can be seen below:

```
--CREATE SCRIPTS
/*put your create scripts here – your script should not commented out*/

-- this is creating a table called Project that contains 3 variables, the primary key being ProjectID
CREATE TABLE Project
(
    ProjID integer,
    ProjName varchar(10),
    ProjStartDate date,
    primary key (ProjID)
)
-- this is creating a table called Bug that has 4 variables, BugID being the primary key 
CREATE TABLE Bug
(
    BugID integer,
    BugType varchar(10),
    BugDesc varchar(10),
    BugTime timestamp(3),
    primary key(BugID)
)

-- this is creating a table called Bug_Project with 2 variables; BugID and ProjectID which combine and make a composite key
CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    BugID integer,
    ProjID integer,
    primary key(BugID, ProjID),
    foreign key(BugID) references Bug (BugID),
    foreign key(ProjID) references  Project (ProjID)
)

CREATE TABLE Engineer
(
    EngineerID integer,
    EngineerName varchar(10),
    EngineerType varchar(20),
    primary key (EngineerID)
)

CREATE TABLE Fix_Allocation
(
    EngineerID integer,
    BugID integer,
    primary key(EngineerID, BugID),
    foreign key(EngineerID) references Engineer (EngineerID),
    foreign key(BugID) references Bug (BugID)
)

CREATE TABLE Test_Allocation
(
    EngineerID integer,
    BugID integer,
    primary key(EngineerID, BugID),
    foreign key(EngineerID) references Engineer (EngineerID),
    foreign key(BugID) references Bug (BugID)
)

CREATE TABLE Note
(
    EngineerID integer,
    BugID integer,
    Note_author varchar(5),
    Note_contents varchar(20),
    primary key(EngineerID, BugID),
    foreign key(EngineerID) references Engineer (EngineerID),
    foreign key(BugID) references Bug (BugID)
)

COMMIT;
--INSERT SCRIPTS
/*put your insert scripts here – your script should not commented out */

INSERT INTO Project(ProjID, ProjName, ProjStartDate) VALUES (00, Project1, DATE '1900-02-14');
```

Comment: If you want `Project1` to be treated as a string (and I think you do), put single quotes around it, like `'Project1'`. Currently Oracle think you're referencing a column or variable named "Project1" which doesn't exist.

Comment: oh thank you very much! I understand that now! Sorry for such a stupid question.

Comment: Aside: You've defined `ProjID` as in integer, but you're inputting the value `00`. That will be implicitly converted to `0` to make it an integer value.

Comment: @EricBrandt I do not really understand what you are suggesting to change could you elaborate? Are you saying there is no point to have it as an integer or to change from 00 to 0?

Comment: @Dillon, I'm just pointing out that `00` isn't a valid integer value. I would guess that you do want ProjID to be an integer, in which case you should change your `INSERT` statement to just be one zero, as it is in scaisEdge's answer, rather than two zeros, as it's shown in the question. On the other hand, if you really want or need the project ID to be two zeros, then the data type will have to be a string to accommodate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for string value use single quote otherwise that value is as  column name

```
  INSERT INTO Project(ProjID, ProjName, ProjStartDate) 
  VALUES ( 0, 'Project1',  DATE '1900-02-14')
```

Comment: I respectfully suggest that OP should leave DATE in place as he had it. The form `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` is an ANSI date literal, which Oracle accepts. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aac20fc0eeaaa9879b4da416e8c58169)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica  ..  correct answer  updated ..  the issue was related  to missing single quote around string that is used  as columnname